# Erasing single element in std::forward_list -- prev_it=it or ++prev_it?

Tags: c++

Let's suppose I have a singly-linked list alike `std::forward_list`. I would like to find a *single* list element matching the predicate, perform a few operations on it and optionally remove it based on another predicate.

So far, I've assembled the following:

```
for (T::iterator it = l.begin(), prev_it = l.before_begin();
        it != l.end();)
{
    if (predicate)
    {
        // ...

        if (another_predicate)
        {
            l.erase_after(prev_it);
            break;
        }
    }

    prev_it = it;
    ++it;
}
```

However, I'm especially wondering if it's the most optimal way of performing the increment part. Alternatively, I have been considering:

```
    ++prev_it;
    ++it;
```

While in plain C the former would be obviously better, in C++ that seems not that clear anymore. I believe that with simpler iterators, the former should be simpler; however, if copying the iterator may involve memory allocation (e.g. when using PImpl), the latter may actually be better.

Which method do you consider superior and why? Please note that I'd like to avoid limiting this strictly to a common `std::forward_list` design and consider a solution which would work with more complex types.

Comment: While there are no guarantees, it's generally expected that container iterators are cheap to copy. I'd be shocked if any implementation of `forward_list::iterator` were implemented as anything other than a pointer to a list node.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: not if you use memory allocation for PImpl… unless I'm missing something.

Comment: another compact way is: prev_it = it++;

Comment: @MichałGórny: Indeed, if someone was insane enough to implement a standard iterator like that, then it would be slow to copy. In that case, I'd look for another library implementation rather than try to work around the shortcomings of this one.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: how would you implement the bridge pattern to hide the implementation of iterators then?

Comment: @lzprgmr: I believe that one has shortcomings of both. First it creates a copy of `it` locally, then moves the original iterator and copies the local copy to `prev_it`…

Comment: @MichałGórny indeed, so I just say it is more compact:)

Comment: @MichałGórny: Unless you want the iterators to be horrendously slow, you don't. Why would you want to?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/remove)?

Comment: @KerrekSB, because it's a bad idea for predicates to maintain state (unless they've changed that in C++11).  Those objects get copied around so it would be hard to guarantee you only remove *one* element.

Comment: @Michael Kristofik The trick with predicate state is that you have to store the state outside the predicate and store a reference/pointer to the state inside the predicate.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: do you see another way of hiding the container implementation from library consumers?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I want the iteration to terminate after finding the element. The piece of code is supposed not to waste time iterating the whole list.

Comment: @MichałGórny: OK, fair enough.

Comment: @MichałGórny Guess what, I don't care for the implementation of an iterator. And if I'm gonna mess with it, it's my fault. So who could possibly profit from hiding the implementation of an iterator, especially since the whole container implementation needs to be visible anyway, since it's templated. Nearly the whole C++ standard library is header-only, nothing hidden there.

Comment: @ChristianRau: it's called ABI. Some of us actually care how they write the code and how useful it will be.

Comment: @MarkB, I wouldn't trust myself to get the external state right unless I already had a `DoThisExactlyOnce` class to inherit from.  Too much work for a function object.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I wasn't saying that. I was saying that you either obviously don't understand the problems with ABI or ignore them. Either way, I hope I won't have to use your libraries.

Comment: @MichałGórny And I was saying that the most part of the standard library *has* to be inline, since it's templated and there is just no point in hiding anything, since there is no ABI when the whole thing is compiled right into your project. So hiding the implementation of a small iterator is useless when the rest of the library, especially the container itself, is inline, anyway.

Comment: @MichałGórny You cannot mix libraries that use different standard library versions anyway. Just hiding the implementation of a small iterator won't help you there, it's a drop in the bucket.

Comment: @ChristianRau: through hiding the implementation you can achieve a simple container return type which has the same external ABI independently of the fact whether it uses `std::vector`, `std::list` or `std::array` internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get really confused when for-loops don't increment their counters, so I would simply add `++prev_it, ++it` to your for-loop.  Your iterators will stay in lockstep (provided you don't mess with them) and the names clearly state what they refer to.  I always err on the side of clarity before worrying about performance.

You probably shouldn't worry about generalizing this code to other containers because `std::forward_list` is a special case.  Other containers don't require things like `erase_after`.

Comment: If you want it directly in the `for`-statement (which is a good idea), why not just say `prev_it = it++`, which is IMHO more clear (since the iterators don't look independent)?

Comment: Because that's two side-effects in one instruction.  I like things to be explicit so I naturally write it the other way.  You make a good point though.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's a matter of taste, I like to be concise and `prev=it, ++it` is two statements for what should be an interlocked operation conceptually.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I agree that for that variant `prev_it = it++` is better. Especially if someone was mad enough to overload `operator,`.

Answer (score 2):

If you write it with two increments instead of the obvious assign-then-increment, all your future maintainers will stare at the code for some time wondering what they're missing and why it's written in such a way.

You should code it in the obvious way (save off prev, then increment), and if your iterators are that expensive to copy where profiling indicates it's a problem, find a better iterator. You shouldn't generally go making code changes like this to work around a problem that may not even noticeably affect your performance.

EDIT: As @Kerrek SB notes in a comment on the question, and you're content with lying slightly about your meaning, you could use `forward_list::remove_if` with a (carefully) stateful predicate to implement this as well.

Comment: I disagree with the original code being obvious, but +1 for mentioning use of a profiler.  I highly doubt incrementing iterators (however you choose to do it) is the bottleneck here, especially in a standard container.